# Store android settings in editable config

Tags: android, configuration

I am looking for the best way to allow developers / testers to point an app to the UAT server rather than the default, PROD, in an android app.  As with .NET or Java, where I would have an app.config or properties file allowing you to change the URL prior to running the app, I would like to understand the common approach on android apps?

The data storage options outlined in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html are clear, but none of them seem to quite fit unless I am missing something.

Shared preferences and InternalStorage seem the best fit, but with shared preferences it looks like I would require root access to modify the file and with InternalStorage no API is provided for parsing the settings, so just wondering if I have missed something obvious.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a slightly different manner by maintaining different build flavours. With different build flavours, you can have different configuration files for different flavours. So make different build flavours one for production and one for testing and put all your files which are different for production and testing separately in two flavour packages and you can build which ever flavour you want.

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) for further reference

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  That's all good and I did consider something similar but we have several UAT server / configurations which different testers may want to use, and so we will to have several builds (all of which are built on a build server and apk files dropped for use).  Additionally, I would prefer that the build that is going out to production is identical to the one we test with?  I'm thinking the internal storage may be the best bet at the moment.